# Run jUnit with CruiseControl.net and show Results in Dashboard of CruiseControl.NET

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, cruisecontrol.net, nant

i'm looking for a way to run jUnitTests from a java project using CruiseControl.net.

I found this on cruisecontrol-webpage:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Step_3_Add_unit_tests

There is an example with nant-script for unittests using visual studio and .net-Framework, but i have Eclipse, a java application and no idea how it works for it.

At the end of the junit test, i need a resultfile to show the resultfiles in cruisecontrol dashboard.